# Prevent IP in URL in response from server

Tags: tomcat, dns

I have a VPS with CentOS and Tomcat installed, and I also have web hotel (on another server) with a domain name included. I'm trying to redirect requests to my domain to my VPS server, and have succeeded doing that. But the problem is, after typing the domain name - for instance http://www.example.com, the host name is translated to my servers IP address in the address bar in the response. How can I prevent the domain name being translated to the IP address in the response? Can this be done by tomcat configuration on my VPS?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is redirecting the user needs to redirect using the hostname, not the IP address.